# Python: print all contents of a pyenchant dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, windows-7, pyenchant

I have loaded a non english dictionary using `hunspell` type 
`.dic` and `.aff` files. I can check a word in the dictionary by using

```
d=enchant.Dict('my_lang')  
d.check('my_word')
```

The `.dic` file contains all base forms and the `. aff` file contains all affixes.
 What i need is to find a base form for an entered word. What would help is if i could print out all `enchant.dict` object contents or take a word in the `.dic`  file and use all affixes to make a list of new words.
Is this possible or do i have to code the affix rules myself?
If the `check()` function already does this why is it so hidden?